# Distribution of data is very separated in my graph

Tags: regression, spss, pre-post-comparison

First post here but I am quite stuck.

I plotted the date an award was given to a university, against their change in score (I calculated an index of change). It has given me this graph which i am struggling to interpret. The data points seem to be very separated out - either in the -10 - .10 region or in the -90 to -60 region.

Is there any way to test for significance, or any tests I should do next? The simple linear regression was not significant (p>0.05).

[image: graph]

Comment: Can you describe what the "change score" is exactly? Is there any obvious differences between the two groupings - such as the lower grouping always having really low "pre" measures.

Comment: You have 2 latent clusters. It doesn't look like there is a relationship b/t X & Y w/i either cluster, but the lower cluster is more common on the right & the upper cluster is more common on the left (hence the slight downward slope).

Answer (score 0):

I am suspicious of the change in score calculation as there is an obvious extreme grouping going on (and really no relationship between date and the change index).  Please explain exactly how you calculated this.